# VSCode on Ubuntu 18.04 cannot run a Python program

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VSCode with Python 3.6 on an Ubuntu 18.04 system. I wrote a "hello world" program.

```
msg = "Hello World"
print(msg)
```

If I highlight it and press shift+enter it runs without problem, but, if I right-click and select to execute the file in a terminal I get this error message.

```
>>> /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/nuria/hello/hello.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/nuria/hello/hello.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I really don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: Never mind, I solved it

Comment: It might be happening because of the `.` in python3.6. Probably the exact path is /use/bin/python3 only.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your terminal is still running python. vscode is trying to execute `/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/nuria/hello/hello.py` in python terminal which is still running from when you executed code using `Shift + Enter`. Just exit python shell and everything should work.